# How to access a stored value in PHPUnit_Extensions_SeleniumTestCase

Tags: selenium, phpunit, selenium-rc

How can I store a value within Selenium-RC (through PHPUnit) and then retrieve/access it later using PHPUnit?

Suppose I run a command like the following in a test:

```
$this->storeExpression( "foo", "bar" );
```

If I understand the Selenium API documentation correctly, I could access this data using `javascript{storedVars['foo']}` using good 'ol fashioned Selenese. It should contain the value `"bar"`.

My question is this: how can I access this `javascript{storedVars['test']}` expression (or, more generally, `javascript{storedVars}` in PHPUnit?

For example, here's a simple test I've run:

```
public function testStorage()
{
    $this->open('http://www.google.com/'); // for example
    $this->storeExpression( 'foo', 'bar' );
    $foo = $this->getExpression('foo');
    echo $foo;
}
```

The output of which is "foo" (among the other standard PHPUnit output), while I expect it should be "bar". It's just giving me back the name of the expression, not its value.

Can anyone with experience in this give me some guidance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good posts in this thread, but looks like no 100% working answer so far.

Based on the Selenium reference here

http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-core/1.0/reference.html#storedVars

It would seem the correct code syntax would be:

```
$this->storeExpression( 'bar', 'foo' );
$foo = $this->getExpression("\${foo}");
```

I haven't tested that exactly, but doing something similar with

```
$this->storeHtmlSource('srcTxt');
$val = $this->getExpression('\${srcTxt}');
print $val;
```

did the trick for me.

Comment: This worked exactly how I expected it to. Sorry you didn't answer sooner, I had a +50 bounty out on this a couple weeks ago!

Answer (score 1):

The PHPUnit Selenium Testcase driver actually understands `storeExpression` and `getExpression`; have a look at its source code. You can do

```
$this->storeExpression('foo', 'bar');
```

and

```
$this->getExpression('foo');
```

Comment: Perhaps I'm doing something wrong. The code snippet's a bit too much for a comment, so I updated my question.

Comment: This just isn't working. `$foo = $this->getExpression('foo');` just sets `$foo` equal to `"foo"`. Is there something else I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

As Selenium Stores the expression result in second argument it stores value in "bar" and when u need to call it you should call the stored name to get the expression.

```
    $this->storeExpression( 'foo', 'bar' );
    $foo = $this->getExpression("bar");
```

May this helps you it worked for me.

EDIT :

```
    $evaluated = $this->getEval("regex:3+3");
    $expressed = $this->getExpression("regex:3+3");
```

The First Evaluated will give the evaluated output for expression
and the second will show the expressed output.
The secound is used to verify that the specified expression is genrated or not by the alert.

Comment: when I run this, `$foo = $this->getExpression('bar');` just sets `$foo` equal to `"bar"`. In fact, `$foo = $this->getExpression( "this is a test" );` sets `$foo` equal to `"this is a test"`. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Does that code snippet actually work for you?

Comment: As per your requirement that the expression should be evaluated the answer is been updated. please see is it helpful